# Measure for controllability of eigenvalues of an LTI system

Tags: control-theory, linear-control

Given the LTI system

$$\dot{x}(t) = Ax(t)+Bu(t),$$

with $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}, B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$. Is there a way to say (in a qualitative way) how controllable an eigenvalue of $A$ is compared to all the other eigenvalues? Something like: "$\lambda_2$ is more controllable than $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_4$ but $\lambda_3 $ is the most controllable (for an $A$ with at least 4 eigenvalues)."

My thoughts: We know $(A,B)$ is controllable iff (using the [PBH-test](https://books.google.de/books?id=UPWAmAXQu1AC&pg=PA133&lpg=PA133&dq=left%20eigenvector%20controllability&source=bl&ots=BG7NwFtGB4&sig=ACfU3U17KlqNOBubHtB_FGPiqj5YDBp0AQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiN9b_8nKLqAhWJDewKHUGvAkMQ6AEwAnoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=left%20eigenvector%20controllability&f=false)) there is no left eigenvector $w$ of $A$ that is orthogonal to the columns of $B$, i.e.

$$ w^\top A = \lambda w^\top, \quad w^\top B = f^\top \neq 0^\top.$$

Now, does the euclidean norm of these $f$'s tell us something about how controllable their corresponding eigenvalues are compared to the other eigenvalues, assuming that all the left eigenvalues $w$ had the same norm?

Comment: What do you mean by "more" or "less" controllable? Either a subspace/states is or isnt controllable. Are you interested in measuring how far down the chain of integrators that subspace is from a control input?

Comment: Usually the controllability Gramian can be used to say something about how "controllable" a certain direction is. However, I do not know if those directions have a correlation with the eigenvectors of $A$.

Comment: The singular value decomposition of the controllability gramian essentially ranks the directions of the state space from most controllable to least controllable. This video gives a more in depth explanation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZNHx62HbKNA.